# How to fix a bricked K20 Pro?

Tags: unbricking

I did something incorrectly to my Xiaomi Redmi K20 Pro, and it's now not turning ON, no bootloader or recovery mode. I found something on XDA developers forum and my phone is currently in EDL mode. It is detected only on COM-port 10. I don't know how to recover it.

How do I fix my phone?

Comment: no worry, just flash official ROM/firmware with MiFlash or QPST

Answer (score 1):

1 year ago I also faced the same problem on my Redmi 3S Prime. It wasn't even detected by MiFlash. After lots of research and 3-4 months I thought to take to a repairing shop. The man at repairing shop just removed back panel and touched at a point on motherboard with screwdriver and inserted the usb cable in the mobile. The computer detected the phone. I don't know what the software he used to flash the device this can help you in your further research.

Comment: that is called test point to get device in EDL mode (where you can flash with MiFlash or QPST)

Comment: But now they came one more step, they now added new one, which is only work authorized person. Now they called it like FRP. i didn't find a way

Comment: When we are connecting display port we can access EDL(Emergency Download Mode). Now MI Flash tool also need authorized person login to flash. i tried edl flash also